# Continuous piecewise smooth function $=$ a globally $\mathcal{C}^1$ function $+\sum a_i|s-\alpha_i|$?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading *Mathematical Tools for the Study of the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations and Related Models*, written by Franck Boyer and Pierre Fabrie. They stated that **Such a piecewise smooth function $\beta$ can be written as the sum of a globally $\mathcal{C}^1$ function and a finite linear combination of functions of the form $s \mapsto |s-\alpha_i|$**, in page 422(see the following picture).
[image]

I'm wondering how can we construct such an expression. Can anyone help me? Or are there any references on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**:WLOG, suppose that there exists only one bad point $\alpha$, then $$\beta(s)=\left(\beta(s)-\frac{\beta_{+}'(\alpha)-\beta_{-}'(\alpha)}{2}|s-\alpha|\right)+\frac{\beta_{+}'(\alpha)-\beta_{-}'(\alpha)}{2}|s-\alpha|$$ $$\triangleq g(s)+\frac{\beta_{+}'(\alpha)-\beta_{-}'(\alpha)}{2}|s-\alpha|.$$ It's easily checked that $g'_-(\alpha) = g'_+(\alpha)$ and hence $g\in \mathcal{C}^1$.